# Filter as replacement for custom routing

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have a cluster with 100's of millions of documents. This is a multi-tenancy setup and each customer has a unique ID.

I have no routing implemented as yet but there was talk of having some custom routing by customer ID, so we know on what shards to go for a specific customer.

I have been playing with filters and wondered if they could provide similar benefit to custom routing but without getting into situations where we have hot spots in the cluster, since not all customers are of equal size, in fact some are huge while others are tiny!

The filters get cached in a bit-set (super compact and efficient) so I was thinking if all my queries had an initial filter applied first and then the query or another filter runs on the result of this?

Is this a sensible compromise to having custom routing? I do not want to end up with hot spots in the cluster which is inevitable feel.